# c++ classes as unions

Tags: c++, oop, memory, unions

I have found out that unions are classes in c++.

If you declare a class as a union:

```
union Foo    // Declare union type
{
    char   ch;

    int func(int a);

};
```

Will the size of the union be 4 or 1 (assuming char size of 1 and pointers size of 4 ) ?

Comment: While both answers are good, neither addresses a specific misunderstanding in your question: member functions (of structs, classes or unions) are _not_ data members.  Although the details are implementation-defined, they usually take _no space_ in instance objects (the partial exception being virtual functions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have found out that unions are classes **too** in c++. (emphasis mine)

<del>No (they are a class-type, not classes).</del>My bad, apparently they are classes:

#### 3.9.2/1

> - [...]
> - unions, which are classes capable of containing objects of different types at different times
> - [...]

(no longer relevant) Unions can't have `virtual` member functions & also can't be used in inheritance.

*Onto the answer:*

The size will be large enough to accommodate the largest data member. In this case, it will likely be `1`, yes.

Comment: note: are there good reasons for those (=vs class) restrictions?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath dunno, ask a question :)

Comment: Also, union can't contains non-static data members of reference type.

Answer (score 2):

Try it yourself:

```
#include <iostream>

union Foo    // Declare union type
{
    char   ch;

    int func(int a);     
};   

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(Foo);
}
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: for c/c++ learning by trial (and error) is not adviced (though in this case it gives the correct answer).

Comment: Though verifying understanding is only possible through trial and error.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: You have a partial point, but experimenting and trying-for-yourself are crucial parts of an interested programmer's life! And I'd much prefer to see a question like "I tried X and observed Y; is this mandated by the langauge?"

Comment: @Kerrek SB: that's perfectly fine for a *Question*. What I'm saying is that it's a wrong mentality for an answer.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: Yeah, I suppose.